# Why does my Java key input work only sometimes?

Tags: java, input, jframe, sprite, keystroke

I've been trying to add some key input to my code for a while now, but for some reason it won't work in one class but in another it works just fine and I don't know why. An Example Here Is the one that DOES work.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
public class KeyStrokeSample {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
  String ACTION_KEY = "theAction";
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("KeyStroke Sample");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  JButton buttonA = new JButton("Press 'W'");

      Action actionListener = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
          JButton source = (JButton) actionEvent.getSource();
            System.out.println(source.getText());

  }
};
KeyStroke W = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W");
InputMap inputMap = buttonA.getInputMap();
inputMap.put(W, ACTION_KEY);
ActionMap actionMap = buttonA.getActionMap();
actionMap.put(ACTION_KEY, actionListener);
frame.add(buttonA);
frame.setSize(400, 200);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

However when I tried to put it into my Sprite class and get the same response NOTHING HAPPENED I've tried changing the order and every time I don't get a response even though their is no error message. The code for that particular problem is below in my main method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
 InterruptedException{

//setting the window and sprites
Sprite orig_world = new Sprite(ImageIO.read(new 
File("C:/Users/sfiel42/Documents/game/castles.png")),0,0);
Sprite world      = new Sprite(ImageIO.read(new 
File("C:/Users/sfiel42/Documents/game/castles.png")),0,0);

JLabel label      = new JLabel(); 
label.setLocation(0,0);
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(world.getSprite()));
label.setVisible(true);   

JFrame frame      = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(783,615);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(label);


Sprite archer = new Sprite(ImageIO.read(new 
File("C:/Users/sfiel42/Documents/game/archer.png")),30,40);

String ACTION_KEY = "theAction";
JButton buttonA = new JButton("Button For W");
Action actionListener = new AbstractAction() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    JButton source = (JButton) actionEvent.getSource();
    System.out.println(source.getText());
  }
};
KeyStroke W = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W");
InputMap inputMap = buttonA.getInputMap();
inputMap.put(W, ACTION_KEY);
ActionMap actionMap = buttonA.getActionMap();
actionMap.put(ACTION_KEY, actionListener);
buttonA.setVisible(false);
frame.add(buttonA);
```

If you want the rest of the sprite class to help figure out what the problem is the whole thing can be found at the link to my other question.
[Why can't I erase my Sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43897694/why-cant-i-erase-my-sprite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is focus related issue.

When you use `getInputMap()`, you asking for the `InputMap` which responds to key events only when the component has keyboard focus.

Instead, consider using [`JComponent#getInputMap(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap-int-) and pass it one of the other conditions, like `JComponent#WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`

Additional, instead of registering the key bindings against the buttons, I'd bind them to the parent component and re-use `Action` with the buttons

```
public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {
    public MoveAction(String name) {
        putValue(NAME, name);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println(getValue(NAME));
    }
}

//...

MoveAction action = new MoveAction("W");
String ACTION_KEY = "theAction";
KeyStroke W = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0);
InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
inputMap.put(W, ACTION_KEY);
ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
actionMap.put(ACTION_KEY, action);

JButton buttonA = new JButton(action);
buttonA.setVisible(false); // This worries me :P
```

Using an `Action` this way produces a much more flexible and re-usable solution

I'd also avoid using things like `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W")`, because this will probably return a `KeyStroke` for <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> which probably isn't what you want.  Instead make use [`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(int,%20int)) which will give you much more control over it

Comment: Well this sort of helps but I was hoping to be able to register keystrokes in the main method of my Sprite class, Is there any way I could do that?

Comment: Key bindings need to be registered against a component which is/will be active on the screen